# how do i pass around a mutable object in rust

Tags: for-loop, rust, borrow-checker

I have some Rust trait for some effects that manipulate the game state by applying them

```
pub struct GameState {some_number : usize}
impl GameState {
  pub fn apply(self, e: &dyn Effect) -> GameState {
     // <do some accounting>
     return e.apply(self);
}

pub trait Effect {    
  fn apply(self, state: GameState) -> GameState;
}
```

in one of the Effects I want to apply another one:

```
pub struct MyFirstEffect;
impl Effect for MyFirstEffect {
  fn apply(self, mut state: GameState) -> GameState{
    for state.some_number > 0 {        
      state = state.apply(&MyOtherEffect::new());
    }
    return state;
  }
}
pub struct MyOtherEffect;
impl Effect for MyFirstEffect {
  fn apply(self, mut state: GameState) -> GameState{
    return GameState{state.some_number +1 }
  }
}
```

It is important for me, that Effect::apply(..) is only called in the GameState::apply(..)  such that I can do some book keeping and maybe apply some other effects that have hooks on certain effects, but that is not the problem here.

My problem is that the borrow checker hates this. I first thought about this like passing a mutable reference around (instead of the "-> GameState") but it does not let me do that: In the loop it complains that the state was already borrowed.
So I came up with this variant where I hand out an immutable GameState every time, which is crazy inefficient, but I thought that's the dumbest and safest way, but the borrow checker doesn't let me do that either because the lifetime of the GameState is not known.
So I tried switching around the & and &mut but nothing is pleasing the borrow checker.
Now I think that I should come up with some error messages that I get. But instead I just want to ask, how do I do such thing in general? Someone who is good in working with Rust should imho know that ad-hoc

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Wouldn't it just be `state = state.apply(...);`?

Comment: The code you've shown more or less works, but isn't complete. In order to solve your problem we will need to see more code — to see what the borrow conflict is. The solution will depend on what the requirements of your program are. I imagine the problem you have is related to `Effect`s being stored in the `GameState`, but that's just a guess.

Comment: You should be using a `&mut self` in your `GameState` method *and* a `&self` in your `Effect` method.

Comment: @BlackBeans yes i should, maybe that was one of my problems

Answer (score 2):

At a glance the main problem you are having is probably something like: "use of moved value: 'state' value moved here, in previous iteration of loop". Though I can't know for certain because you haven't posted the error the borrow checker is giving you. Regardless if that were the case, the cause of the problem would be that `Copy` isn't implemented for `GameState` and you are moving it into the context of `GameState::apply`.

Problem one can be solved three ways:

1. Implement copy for `GameState`. (This fixes the borrow checker issue but wouldn't achieve the behaviour you desire because state would remain unchanged by the end of `MyFirstEffect::apply`)
2. Follow @cdhowie's suggestion which takes back the mutated state so that it can be mutated again in the next loop iteration. (This is the answer to how your question, but it's not the solution I would go with.)
3. Change the `apply` functions to accept mutable references. (I would recommend this option because it avoids the issue of moving more and more data as the contents of `GameState` grows. All you need to move is a reference, which is of a fixed size regardless how big `GameState` is.)

Option three would look something like this:

```rust
pub struct GameState {some_condition: usize}
impl GameState {
    pub fn apply(&mut self, e: &dyn Effect) {
        // NOTE: for state.someCondition > 0 is incorrect for two reasons and
        // confusing for one. Incorrect because:
        // 1. Using `for` here is not consistent with rust's syntax. A while
        //   loop should be used instead.
        // 2. Rust variable names and struct fields are generally written in
        //    snake_case rather than camelCase.
        // 
        // And it's a little confusing because the `some_condition` variable is
        // not a condition, it's some value.
        while self.some_condition > 0 {
            e.apply_to(self);
        }
    }
}

pub trait Effect {
    // Consider changing `apply` -> `apply_to` because you are applying the
    // effect onto the state rather than the state onto the effect, and it keeps
    // the function distinct from `GameState::apply`.
    fn apply_to(&self, state: &mut GameState);
}

struct ZeroCondition;
impl Effect for ZeroCondition {
    fn apply_to(&self, state: &mut GameState) {
        state.some_condition -= 1;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut state = GameState {some_condition: 3};
    state.apply(&ZeroCondition);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all of that!
(1) was not the problem.
I got a minimal example of (2) working. Though you are right, I don't want to do (2). 
In your example you put the loop in the GameStates logic, I want it in the Effect. However I also got a minimal version working of (3).

Comment: Problem is when I do the exact signatures in my actual project it does complain because I want to reference something from the state
""let player = &(state.players[self.base.target_player as usize]);""
I want to use the player reference in the condition (i tried to simplify it in my example). So is there something else I can do other than inlining it there?

Comment: @user19831231 Sorry, I can't help you unless I know the errors you're getting or what the context is for the line of code you have supplied above. Ultimately, further guidance is likely outside the scope of the question, but good luck with your project!